# addEventListener a un option de un select

Tags: javascript

Estoy teniendo problemas para adicionar un *event listener* a multiples option de un select... Mi pagina toma una peticion del servidor que regresa un **json** y a partir de este creo un elemento HTML *option* con
un valor (esto funciona bien) pero cuando intento adicionar un `addEventListener('click')` a esta misma option para que muestre valores de mi json dentro de mi HTML no me funciona.. no veo donde esta el error en mi funcion... en el navegador veo que esta el handler dentro de cada option(imagen debajo) pero no hace nada... Saludos

```js
const statesElement = document.querySelector('#states')
const infoElement = document.querySelector("#info");

function setUSStates(states) {
  states.forEach((state) => {
    const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    optionElement.setAttribute("value", state.name);
    optionElement.textContent = state.name;
    optionElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
      infoElement.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(state)}</pre> `;
    });
    
    statesElement.append(optionElement);
  });
}


async function getUSStates() {
  /* seria asi...
  const response =  await fetch ('/api/states')
  const states  = await response.json()
  
  states me regresa un json desde mi servidor en este formato 
  */
  const states = [
    {name: "Alabama", code: "AL"}, 
    {name: "Alaska", code: "AK"},
    {name: "Arizona", code: "AZ"},
    {name: "Arkansas", code: "AR"}]
  await setUSStates(states);
}

getUSStates()
```

```html
<select name="" id="states"></select>
<div id="info"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no puedes añadir un evento al tag `option`. Puedes escuchar el evento `change` en el `select`.

Comment: probé con change pero no funciona igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así. He definido los `states` como variable global para que se pueda acceder desde cualquier sitio.

Y en el `change` se hace un `find` para buscar el `state` con el `name` que tenga el `option`.

```js
const statesElement = document.querySelector('#states')
const infoElement = document.querySelector("#info");
let states = [];

statesElement.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const state = states.find(state => state.name === e.target.value);
   infoElement.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(state)}</pre> `;
});

function setUSStates(states) {
  states.forEach((state) => {
    const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    optionElement.setAttribute("value", state.name);
    optionElement.textContent = state.name;
    statesElement.append(optionElement);
  });
}


async function getUSStates() {
  /* seria asi...
  const response =  await fetch ('/api/states')
  const states  = await response.json()
  
  states me regresa un json desde mi servidor en este formato 
  */
  states = [
    {name: "Alabama", code: "AL"}, 
    {name: "Alaska", code: "AK"},
    {name: "Arizona", code: "AZ"},
    {name: "Arkansas", code: "AR"}]
  await setUSStates(states);
}

getUSStates()
```

```html
<select name="" id="states"></select>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hawks tome tu codigo e hice algo muy parecido a lo que tenia antes y tu solucion... con el states global es practico.. saludos

Comment: Podrías guardar en el `value` del `option` el índice del `state` en el arreglo `states`, para después utilizarlos para obtener la info de este, de esta forma te podrías evitar iterar para saber cuál es. Esto, siempre y cuando no se modifique el orden.

Comment: Lo que comentas es una buena solución para evitar la iteración. Pero en el caso de que manipule el array `state` los índices pueden cambiar y puede acarear inconsistencias.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas suscribirte al evento `change` del `select` para obtener la opción seleccionada.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const statesElement = document.querySelector('#states')
const infoElement = document.querySelector("#info");

// ACA nos suscribimos al cambio de opcion del select
statesElement.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  // ACA obtenemos el option seleccionado
  let option = evt.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0];
  infoElement.innerHTML = `<pre>${option.dataset.info}</pre> `;
});

function setUSStates(states) {
  states.forEach((state) => {
    const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    optionElement.setAttribute("value", state.name);
    optionElement.textContent = state.name;
    // ACA guardamos el state en formato JSON 
    optionElement.dataset.info = JSON.stringify(state);
    statesElement.append(optionElement);
  });
}


async function getUSStates() {
  /* seria asi...
  const response =  await fetch ('/api/states')
  const states  = await response.json()
  
  states me regresa un json desde mi servidor en este formato 
  */
  const states = [
    {name: "Alabama", code: "AL"}, 
    {name: "Alaska", code: "AK"},
    {name: "Arizona", code: "AZ"},
    {name: "Arkansas", code: "AR"}]
  await setUSStates(states);
}


getUSStates()
```

```html
<select name="" id="states"></select>
<div id="info"></div>
```

---

#### Referencias:

- [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- [select.selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)
- [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos.. veo que creas un dataset info en el objeto donde pones toda la info correspondiente y luego un event listener fuera de la funcion para que al hacer un change en el select obtener la info correspondiente de la option.